# свой пример LINQ - совместимой коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Видимо, у меня не очень умный вопрос...

Я пытаюсь лучше понять LINQ, на котором "пишут структурированные запросы к локальным коллекциям".

Ок. С коллекциями типа

```
    string[] myNumbers = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

всё понятно. Хочу поэкспериментировать со своей коллекцией!

Прочитал, что "а LINQ можно запрашивать любую коллекцию, реализующую интерфейс IEnumerable".

Беру [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.11.php) с Метанита и... у меня есть класс, у этого класса есть GetEnumerator(), но LINQ- метод .ToList() я у него вызвать не могу.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace TryIenu
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] myNumbers = { "one", "two", "three" };
                // в следующей строке Linq работает
                List<string> tmp1 = myNumbers.ToList();

                Week w = new();
                // а здесь - не работает
                List<string> tmp2 = w.ToList();
            }
        }

        class Week : IEnumerable{
            string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return new WeekEnumerator(days);
            }
        }

        class WeekEnumerator : IEnumerator{
            string[] days;
            int pozition = -1;
            public WeekEnumerator(string[] days) => this.days = days;

            public object Current{
                get{
                    if (pozition<=-1 || pozition>days.Length)
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    return days[pozition];
                }
            }

            public bool MoveNext(){
                if (pozition<days.Length-1){
                    pozition++;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public void Reset() => pozition = -1;
        }
    }
```

я понимаю, что я ошибаюсь в чём то очевидном. Возможно, просто смотрю не в тот пример. Как бы мне исправить этот пример, или посоветуйте мне какой то пример собственной реализации LINQ - совместимой коллекции?

Мне в комментариях написали, что нужно реализовывать `IEnumerable<T>`, и `GetEnumerator<T>`.

Я реализовал, но код приобрел загадочность, которой раньше в нём не было.

Например, если раньше в коде было просто

```
    public object Current{get{...}};
```

то теперь есть два метода:

```
    public string Current{get{...}}
```

и

```
    object IEnumerator.Current{get{...}}
```

причем ни один из этих методов убрать нельзя, и модификатор public - ни убрать, ни добавить нельзя.

я не понимаю, почему реализовать `IEnumerator<string>` **настолько** сложнее, чем просто `IEnumerator`

Если можно - подскажите? может, я всё таки где то ошибся?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace TryIenu
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] myNumbers = { "one", "two", "three" };
                // в следующей строке Linq работает
                List<string> tmp1 = myNumbers.ToList();

                Week w = new();
                // теперь и здесь - работает!
                List<string> tmp2 = w.ToList();
            }
        }

        class Week : IEnumerable<string>{
            string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                                "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
            IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return new WeekEnumerator(days);
            }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        class WeekEnumerator : IEnumerator<string>{
            string[] days;
            int pozition = -1;
            public WeekEnumerator(string[] days) => this.days = days;

            public string Current{
                get{
                    if (pozition<=-1 || pozition>days.Length)
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    return days[pozition];
                }
            }

            object IEnumerator.Current {
                get{
                    if (pozition<=-1 || pozition>days.Length)
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    return days[pozition];
                }
            }
            
            public void Dispose() {}

            public bool MoveNext(){
                if (pozition<days.Length-1){
                    pozition++;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public void Reset() => pozition = -1;
        }
```

Comment: потому что нужно реализовывать [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0), и [`GetEnumerator<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-ienumerable-1-getenumerator)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло, но добавило новые загадки: теперь каждый метод - двоится. У него есть две версии: с модификатором доступа public и без

Comment: смотри примеры по ссылке. Два вида методов, один с generic параметром, второй без

Comment: еще раз спасибо! По той ссылке, которая на Метанит? я там до конца прочитал страницу, видел, что там есть пример с <T>. Но у меня код почему то полчился вдвое сложнее

Comment: По ссылке на msdn, в моем первом комментарии

Comment: все из-за вот этого `IEnumerable<out T> : System.Collections.IEnumerable` - каждый `IEnumerable<out T>` является и просто `IEnumerable` - поэтому его методы тоже должны быть реализованы. Как правило в них добавляется вызов generic версии.

Comment: > поэтому его методы тоже должны быть реализованы - понял, круто! Осталось понять, почему не удаётся обоим методам дать модификатор доступа public...

Comment: Так как используется [**явная реализация интерфейса**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: `IInterface.MyMethod` замените на `public MyMethod` и все получится.

Comment: `object IEnumerator.Current => Current;`, то же самое с методами.

Comment: @aepot. _IInterface.MyMethod замените на public MyMethod_ - не всегда так можно